# How can I get byteSize of String Array other than traversing the Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, bytebuffer

I want to optimize my code by using ByteBuffer in place of String. What I am getting is String[]. I am doing formatting on each element of it.

e.g. `String strAry[] = {"Help", "I", "am", "trapped", "in", "a", "fortune", "cookie", "factory"};`

is my String array, I am writing content of it to a .csv file in 
format "StrArray[0]";"StrArray[1]";"StrArray[2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)";"StrArray[3]"; so on...

which is internally creating multiple Strings and this code is running into loop for hundreds n thousands of time some time.

I want to implement [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html). While creating

ByteBuffer bbuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferSize); I need to specify buffer size here.

I dont want to iterate over each element of String [] to calculate its byteSize.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: And you can't use StringBuffer to do the job?

Comment: Yes I can, But when this process is runnig for multiple times. n number of StringBuffers are created and at the end I need to convert it to String so in single run one StringBuffer and one String is created which is memory eating process.

Comment: Due to the nature of object memory, *something somewhere* will need to traverse the string array in order to get the byte size of each string, as this isn't information known at the array's level; it's probably just best to use a StringBuffer, but if you are dedicated to ByteBuffer, you'll need to just loop through all of the strings and sum their byte sizes.

Comment: It's very unclear why using a ByteBuffer, or even a StringBuffer or StringBuilder BTW, would be useful to create a CSV file. That sure looks like unneeded, premature optimization. Writing to a file is several orders of magnitude slower than handling strings in memory. So optimizing the string handling will probably not lead to any significant difference anyway.

Comment: @JBNizet The data I need to write into csv file is not ready to dump into the file. I am creating content of file row by row using different parameters which is including so much string operations. This process is repeating  for  thousand number of rows. I am trying to optimize my program to use less memory and minimise garbage collection process.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of notes:

1. **Data structure usage**

   - I think you should be using **`CharBuffer`** and not `ByteBuffer`. `CharBuffer` is requiring the number of characters and not bytes.

     - Buffers from Java NIO are always used as buffers, that means there is a possibility that you will need to read into them multiple times.
     - If you need to have the whole content in memory, buffers are not the data structure for this use case.
     - You don't have to know the exact size for a buffer, the allocated size is the maximal capacity of the buffer.
   - `StringBuilder` is a mutable data structure for string processing. You might consider using it instead.

     - You don't have to know the exact size.
2. **Computation of final size**

   - might be done using Stream API (Java 8) or similar utility methods.

Comment: yes I will be using CharBuffer internally for String operations but initialization of Charbuffer also takes input size same as ByteBuffer. e.g. CharBuffer chbuff = CharBuffer.allocate(buffer_size);         Can Size of CharBuffer or ByteBuffer be dynamically increased.                                                       My current implementation uses StringBuffer indeed.